# Excel form date format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form a text box to enter the Month and year in this format **`Dec-15`**, but it actually returns the **`value 15/12/2016`** in the VBA code.

How can I make it 01/12/2015?

```
sMonthYear = Trim(Form.txtMonthYear.Value)
```

report heading = Dec-15

```
Sheets("Report").Cells(2, 2).Value = "" & sMonthYear & ""
```

find Folder = 2015

```
sFolderYear = Year(sMonthYear)
strSavePath = sFilePath + sFolderYear + "\"
```

File name = Dec-15

```
sFileName = sMonthYear
wbDest.SaveAs strSavePath & sFileName & ".xls"
```

Thanks

Comment: `Userform.TextBox.Text` should return the string `"Dec-15"` as it is (you can convert it then by your needs)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, what is I need it to be the date value as i'm also using this value to to determine the year folder to save the file into once a report is created. The "Dec-15" is more for headings and file name.

Comment: have you tried something like: `replace(datevalue("01." & Userform.TextBox.Text),"-"," 20")`?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: dateVal = Format(Userform.TextBox.Text, "Short Date")

Comment: *Dec 15* without a year isn't a date by itself. When you add the year, Excel is going to format it to the ShortDateFormat (defined in Control Panel) by default. If you want it different than that, format the column on your sheet to a different format, either using the dialog or in code using NumberFormat. Using it to make up a string, you can use any or all parts of the date in any way you want; it's a string at that point, not a date.

Comment: Thanks to all the comments provided. I've just changed it to be Dec-2015, and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = "01" & "" & sMonthYear & ""
```

Or Format The Cell

```
Option Explicit
Sub DateFormat()
    Dim sMonthYear As String

    sMonthYear = "Dec-15"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value = "01" & "" & sMonthYear & ""

End Sub
```